# Sum a grouped subquery

Tags: mysql, group-by, sum, subquery

I need to divide the sum of two columns in a subquery, grouped by a third field as follows:

```
Team    |    Score     |    MaxScorePossible
--------------------------------------------
A       |      10      |     15
A       |      12      |     20
B       |      5       |     15
B       |      7       |     20
```

My code is something like this:

```
SELECT (sumScore/sumMaxScore) as Percentage
FROM
(SELECT 
   sum(Score) as sumScore 
   FROM tableScore
   GROUP BY Team ) tbl1,
(SELECT 
   sum(MaxScorePossible) as sumMaxScore 
   FROM tableScore
   GROUP BY Team ) tbl2,
GROUP By Team
```

The output I am hoping for is something like:
A => 0.62, B => 0.34

The problem is clearly that I am grouping both the subquery and the parent query but I don't know how to group one and cause the other to group similarly.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need subqueries.

```
SELECT Team, SUM(Score)/SUM(MaxScorePossible) AS Percentage
FROM tableScore
GROUP BY Team
```

If you did want to use subqueries, you have to join them.

```
SELECT tbl1.Team, (sumScore/sumMaxScore) as Percentage
FROM
    (SELECT 
       Team, sum(Score) as sumScore 
       FROM tableScore
       GROUP BY Team ) tbl1
JOIN
    (SELECT 
       Team, sum(MaxScorePossible) as sumMaxScore 
       FROM tableScore
       GROUP BY Team ) tbl2 
ON tbl1.Team = tbl2.Team
```